# Make smoother lines in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a `StreamPlot` with few streamlines, but I would like these streamlines to be smooth, and they are not.
Here is the code

```
B[g_] := -1 - g^2 + 1/10 g^3
zz = NSolve[B[g] == 0, g][[2, 1, 2]];

StreamPlot[-{Re[B[a + I b]], Im[B[a + I b]]}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2.2, 2.2}, Axes -> False, 
StreamPoints -> {{1, 0}, {Re[zz], Im[zz] - .4}, {Re[zz], -Im[zz] + .4}, {1, .32}, {1, -.32}},
StreamScale -> None, Frame -> None, StreamStyle -> {Red, "Arrow"}, AspectRatio -> .8, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> Large]
```

and the result is [image]

As you can see this has the problem that the streamlines are not always smooth (especially when they are turning a lot). How can I make it so that they are smoother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
postprocess = # /. Line[x_] :> Line[BSplineFunction[x] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/1000]] &;

sp = StreamPlot[-{Re[B[a + I b]], Im[B[a + I b]]}, {a, -2,  2}, {b, -2.2, 2.2}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  StreamPoints -> {{1, 0}, {Re[zz], Im[zz] - .4}, {Re[zz], -Im[zz] + .4}, 
     {1, .32}, {1, -.32}}, 
  StreamScale -> None, Frame -> None, StreamStyle -> {Red, "Arrow"}, 
  AspectRatio -> .8, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ImageSize -> Large];

postprocess @ sp
```

[image]

```
i = 1; 
Row[Show[#, PlotRange -> {{-.5, .5}, All}, ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotLabel -> ((Style[#, 20] & /@ {"sp", "postprocess @ sp"})[[i++]])] & /@ 
 {sp, postprocess@sp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]